# "Object base domain not allowed" facebook debugger is showing . Why?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, facebook-comments

the following error is coming when i debug the URL, where i have implemented facebook comments:

```
Errors That Must Be Fixed
Object Base Domain Not Allowed  Object at URL 'http://164.100.153.101/Egras/default.aspx' of type 'website' is invalid because the domain '164.100.153.101' is not allowed for the specified application id '224885XXXXXXXXXX'. You can verify your configured 'App Domain' at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/224885XXXXXXXXX.
```

whats that mean please reply . Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [facebook Error App Domain: \*\*\*\*\* is not a valid domain.?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330690/facebook-error-app-domain-is-not-a-valid-domain)

Answer (score 0):

Change the App Domain to `164.100.153.101` in your app's Config Settings at https://developers.facebook.com/apps/224885XXXXXXXXX

Comment: its giving me error: Error
App Domains: 164.100.153.101 is not a valid domain. I have written this in Basic info --> App domain

Comment: Try using a domain name, and make sure it's the same one as in your app settings