# Setting up Facebook App Domain as IP Address

Tags: facebook, facebook-login, facebook-apps

I have a login with facebook on my website which I was testing locally on `localhost`. Now I have put it on a server and I am trying to change the facebook app configuration so I could make the login. Before I had:

```
App Domain:
localhost

Site URL:
http://localhost/

Mobile URL:
http://localhost/
```

Now I am trying to change localhost for my website IP address: `107.170.**.**7:8776`, so first I set the Site URL and Mobile URL to `http://107.170.**.**7:8776/` but when I try to set the App domain to `107.170.**.**7:8776` I get an exclamation saying:

```
This must be derived from Canvas URL, Secure Canvas URL, Unity Binary URL, Site URL, Mobile Site URL, Page Tab URL or Secure Page Tab URL. Check and correct the following domains: 107.170.**.**7:8776
```

What am I missing here?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Facebook appears to require a valid domain instead of an IP address. Not sure why, as they don't mention this in the facebook developer docs anywhere (from what I can tell)

More info:
[facebook Error App Domain: [IP Address] is not a valid domain.?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9330690/facebook-error-app-domain-is-not-a-valid-domain)